# Can I change the wal_level from logical to replica? If so are any impact on the replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-11

Is there a chance to change the wal_level from logical to replica without any impact. I know this involves a restart of services but is this possible?

Comment: This might be better asked on the sister site, http://DBA.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to use logical decoding or logical replication, that is a safe thing to do.